# Custom Edit Form for Drop Off Library doesn’t work properly

Tags: custom-form, content-organizer

I have to customize edit form for the Drop Off Library – add some additional fields from external content type Partner, define certain field to be in Display mode ...

So, I created a custom edit form in the SP Designer for the Drop Off Library on which is defined a Content Organizer Rule, and then set the custom edit form as the default edit form. But it doesn’t work properly.

After filling all required properties in the custom edit form and clicking the Save button, the document doesn’t move to the library defined in the Content Organizer Rule. With a default edit form everything works fine. It seems that the Content Organizer Processing job doesn’t start when a custom edit form is used.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the button when saving say Submit or Save?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with DropIffLibrary and Custom Edit Forms.