# Submitting a document in a drop off library using a custom form

Tags: custom-form, content-organizer, drop-off-library

[Here is an old post with the same issue.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12297/custom-edit-form-for-drop-off-library-doesn-t-work-properly)

I am using a drop off library and it works great OOTB.  However, I would like to use a custom edit form.  I can create the form and use it no problem, but when saving it, it only saves the document and doesn't submit it.

When I compare the two forms, I immediately see that the default one has a button that says "Submit", whereas the custom one has a button that says "Save".

Can I edit my custom form so it will submit rather than just save?

Is there a way I can change this `<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>` to a submit?  I did some basic searching but couldn't find anything on `SharePoint:SubmitButton`.